# Play password protected mp3 song in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to play password protected mp3 song in xamarin android.

currently i am using :

CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(https://streams.moodmedia.com/streams/paytel_roadhouse.mp3);

[image]

But it gives me the error 
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://streams.moodmedia.com/streams/paytel_roadhouse.mp3`

I have also tried to add headers :

`CrossMediaManager.Current.RequestHeaders`

But nothing works for me when i hit this request in browser it prompt me for username and password but in the app it is giving me error . So, anyone who have worked with password protect mp3 song in xamarin android can give me any hint how can i play password protected mp3 songs in media player?

Comment: It is worth noting that it is not that the mp3 is password protected, but that the server requires HTTP authenticaton.

Comment: You can't password protect an mp3 file.  A file not found error is exactly that - the file is not found.  It's because the server requires authentication, which is a completely different thing.  If the mp3 library you are using can accept authentication parameters then that's what you need to be looking at.

Comment: to access the URL, you have to add basic auth header to your request. Not sure that `CrossMediaManager` is able to do that.

Comment: I have already password protected mp3 file from third party they have provided password protected file for security purpose now i have to play that song in the player for which i have used crossmediamanager but it shows me error

Comment: I have tried CrossMediaManager.Current.RequestHeaders(key,value) but still the same error. Is there any other way of doing this in xamarin android?